# My variables aren't dividing and I don't understand why

Tags: python

I'm making a simple code that is just meant to print the average scores for a class and individual students. Everything works except for the following set of code:

```py
testSum = testScore1 + testScore2 + testScore3
testAverageStudent = testSum / 3

print("Thank you. The average score for ", StudentName, " was ", testAverageStudent)
```

I don't know why, but whenever I start the code, I get an error message saying `

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int"
```

If anyone could help, that would be wonderful.

Comment: the error msg is very  clear. Please show your complete code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do a division you need to have two numbers. Here one of the variables is a string, that's why it says `str`.

You need to "cast" your variables to `int` or `float` depending on your need.

For example this will work if testScore1, testScore2 and testScore3 can be converted to the type `int` which refers to Integer:

```py
testSum = int(testScore1) + int(testScore2) + int(testScore3) 
testAverageStudent = testSum / 3
```